# How to replace the url into na if there is no file

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shiny-server, dt

i have a data table in shiny app in the table there is an option called click to view documents. How to chance dynamically if there is no file, the data table will shown as there is no data so dont click or how to show the empty text if there is no file in the link.

```
c = data.frame(link = c("https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf?hsLang=en",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/"
           ))

c$link <- paste0("<a href='",c$link,"'target='_blank'>Click here to view the Document</a>")

DT::datatable(c, rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 1000,scrollX = TRUE, dom = 't',columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'),list(width = '75px', targets = 3)))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RCurl::url.exists()` to have a solid check but all depends on your data as it is taking relative quite some time if you have many url's of course. If your situation is just having a directory url ending with "/" versus a file you could chose to do a match on the last character and if that is a "/" there is no file and if not there is. Here the example using the real check of existance.

```
library(RCurl)
library(data.table)

c = data.frame(link = c("https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf?hsLang=en",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/",
           "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/"
           ))

setDT(c) # as I prefer to work with data.table

c[, link := ifelse(RCurl::url.exists(link), paste0("<a href='", link, "'target='_blank'>Click here to view the Document</a>"), ""), by = link]
```

Comment: Where you are calling the statment where /" is not then there is no file @Merjin van Tilborg

Comment: No I showed you an example to check the url if it exists or not using the RCurl package, I also suggested an alternative approach, but did not work that out for you.

Comment: i tried seems its not working